# How to make a spinning wheel for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make a fidget spinner simulator for iOS. I am somewhat of a beginner, but I've done some research. However, I still can't find the answer to the following question:

How do I find the speed and direction of the swipe of a user, and set the speed of my image rotation to the swipe speed?

Comment: Just reading the subject line, you don't really have to do anything - just leave Xcode alone and you're virtually guaranteed to get a spinning wheel 

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a physics simulator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UIPanGestureRecognizer to get the speed of swipe, but for the direction, you should compare the start point and end point of the swipe action and figure out the direction.

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint velocity = [gestureRecognizer velocityInView:yourView];
}
```

[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity)

Answer (score 0):

I use those functions below to create a roulette that's move according to the finger position.

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

Check out this article:
https://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2012/02/13/an-one-finger-rotation-gesture-recognizer/